# PostGIS: Finding points within certain radius from other points

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I have a table in PostgreSQL/PostGIS named `trip` with two geometry columns: `source_geom` (`POINT`) and `destination_geom` (`POINT`) indicating starting and ending location of a journey.

I have one more separate table named `business` with geometry column `office_geom` (`POINT`) that indicates the location of offices.

My aim is to select the records from the table `trip` whose destination is within 1000 meters from *any of the office location*.

What query do I need to fire to get the results that I require?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using subquery or joins. Example using subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM business 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM trip
    WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(trip.destination_geom, business.office_geom) < 1000
)
```

But this query will not use indexes and can take a long time on big datasets. If you need this, you can create `geography` columns from `geometry`, create spatial indexes on geography columns, and use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html):

```
select * 
  from business b
  join trip t on ST_DWithin(trip.destination_geogr, business.office_geogr, 1000)
```